# Is this NOT too-broad of a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

There's currently a featured question in [tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tkinter), [manipulating values in Tkinter [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48774830/7032856). I believe it is *too broad*. Is it not? Is it something else? I believe it is clear that it could use some form of improvement but I am doubting myself as the OP believes it is a valid question(see the comments) as is.

Comment: how I see it: help vampire wasting his/her rep placing a bounty on a bad question to get answers. It's not upvoted but there are answers for the bounty. I personnally think it's unclear.

Comment: I don't see the harm in waiting for the bounty to expire, and then closing it. Ideally, questions like this should be closed before they're eligible for a bounty. But since this one managed to slip through, and is not _extraordinarily bad_ (imo), waiting for the bounty to expire, then closing is the most obvious choice.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What are you talking about? OP already paid for their bounty, and will be able to award if they chose to.

Comment: you're right. My bad. Never placed a bounty before. but the rest of my comment is still on: the question will just get more downvotes until it's closed. Bounty backfires!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you ignore all of the prior existing code (since it's not really applicable to the actual question to begin with), you're left with this block:

> ...but here instead of putting dates manually in field (as 1.1.2017,2.2.2017...) I want to map it to a button , example in my GUI I want to put (JAN-DEC month and 2017, 2018 year) as buttons so that when I select the respective buttons of month and year it should provide the total downtime of that particular month (i,e. monthly downtime) and not downtime from selected month to till date which the current code provides.

We've closed questions like this before as too broad.  It doesn't matter if they've got code to back up their original work; if they don't have an actual question to go with their code and back up what it is they're asking about, that's a fairly strong "too broad" indicator.

Since it's got a bounty attached to it, your only hope is to flag a moderator, explain why you feel like this is off-topic, *potentially* link them to this MSO post, and hope for the best.

Comment: Well, the other option is to wait and then close, right? A completed bounty doesn't preclude closing after the bounty period, yeah?

Comment: I still think that a simple test of whether an SO question actually contains a question mark would weed out a lot of bad stuff!

Comment: @SList:  I disagree since it's be thoroughly unreliable and tough to get right.  We would run the risk of breaking lots of decent and serviceable questions for the sake of a handful of bad ones.

Comment: Well I am half-joking (yes, I know, a sin on SO) rather than making a feature request, but I do think it's more than a handful of bad ones.  It's my impression that most of the can't-be-bothered questions don't have question marks.  The above example is typical - no actual question has been defined.